# Why is my script getting stuck before it reaches the loop?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="content-1"></div>
<div id="content-2"></div>
<div id="content-3"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Write HTML with JS
    document.getElementById("content-1").innerHTML = '<h1>Title</h1>...and more';
    document.getElementById("content-2").innerHTML = 'hello';

    let value = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < aR.length; i++){
        value += aR[i]['name'] + ": " + aR[i]['price'] + "<br/>";
    }
    document.getElementById("content-3").innerHTML = 'hi!';
</script>
```

For some reason my code seems to never reach the third `document.getElementById` statement. The value for that third statement is supposed to be `value` not the string `hi`; I thought the initial problem was with `value` so I set `content-3` as the string `"hi"` but now I've realized that my script doesn't even run till that point.

Does anyone know what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: can i know that what is aR in your case? because it seems you're using its length to run the loop and if that's an error that's why the code execution stops

Comment: What's the value aR?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Have you tried adding a `console.log()` inside the loop to see if you have an infinite loop?

Answer (score -1):

as Muhammad Asif said, its aR declare?
for example just add these and will work

```
 var aR = {
        0: { name: "XX", price: "55" },
        1: { name: "YY", price: "55" }
    };
```

all the code for example

```
<div id="content-1"></div>
<div id="content-2"></div>
<div id="content-3"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var aR = {
        0: { name: "XX", price: "55" },
        1: { name: "YY", price: "55" }
    };

    // Write HTML with JS
    document.getElementById("content-1").innerHTML = '<h1>Title</h1>...and more';
    document.getElementById("content-2").innerHTML = 'hello';

    let value = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < aR.length; i++) {
        value += aR[i]['name'] + ":" + aR[i]['price'] + "<br/>";
        
    }
    document.getElementById("content-3").innerHTML = 'hi!';
</script>
```

by declaring the aR object will run all the code

Answer (score -2):

first of all, only run this line and check whether your script is running or not.

```
document.getElementById("content-1").innerHTML = '<h1>Title</h1>...and more';
```

check, is this line is displayed?

second, What is this aR? Did you declare it before?

```
     aR.length;
```